# Error in R: Error in { : task 1 failed - "'x' must be numeric"

Tags: r

Getting the following error in R while running GLMNet regression:

- Error in { : task 1 failed - "'x' must be numeric"

Answer (score -1):

Do you just need to make it numeric?

```
Df$x <- as.numeric(Df$x)
```